# What's wrong wih this AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I'm trying to teach myself how to use AJAX and I'm wondering what I did wrong with this example code?

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_info.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```
<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
```

Here's a demo of my code: http://davidc.site40.net/AJAX/index.html

Comment: It's good that you have a working demo of your problem, but you should put the relevant code in your question.  That way if/when this link breaks, the question may still useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access a different domain in your Ajax request. Most modern browsers will block that to prevent cross-site scripting.

For example, Chrome's developer console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) tells you:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_info.txt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://davidc.site40.net' is therefore not allowed access.